# how to fixs C# DontNetty client can not receive from Java Netty i

Tags: java, c#, netty

The Netty Server can received info from DontNetyy Client
But,DontNetty Client can not received info form Netty Server

They are use protobuf serialize object

c# client

```
   var bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
            bootstrap
                .Group(group)
                .Channel<TcpSocketChannel>()
                .Option(ChannelOption.TcpNodelay, true)
                .Option(ChannelOption.SoKeepalive,true)
                .Handler(new ActionChannelInitializer<ISocketChannel>(channel =>
                {
                    IChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.Pipeline;



                    pipeline.AddLast(new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());

                    pipeline.AddLast(new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
                    pipeline.AddLast(new EchoClientHandler());
                }));

            IChannel clientChannel = await bootstrap.ConnectAsync(new IPEndPoint(ClientSettings.Host, ClientSettings.Port));
```

java server

```
    bootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline p = socketChannel.pipeline();


            p.addLast(new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());

            p.addLast(MessageCodec.PROTO_DECODER, new ProtobufDecoder(BaseMsgOuterClass.BaseMsg.getDefaultInstance()));



            p.addLast(new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
            p.addLast(new ProtobufEncoder());


            p.addLast(serverHandler);
        }
    });
```

Server send info to client.
but the c# client read0 metho is not called.

```
public class EchoClientHandler : SimpleChannelInboundHandler<BaseMsgC>
{


    protected override void ChannelRead0(IChannelHandlerContext ctx, BaseMsgC msg)
    {
        Console.Write("ChannelRead0 is not called ");
        Console.Write(msg.Msg);
        Console.Write(msg.MsgType);
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void ChannelRead(IChannelHandlerContext context, object message)
    {

        Console.Write("ChannelRead is called");
    }     
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with DotNetty but my guess is that you add a `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` that only reads `BaseMsgC` and you aren't decoding your `IByteBuffer` into a `BaseMsgC`. There are two ways to solve that problem.

1. Change the generic in your `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` to `IByteBuffer` or
2. Change your handler pipeline so it's able to decode the `IByteBuffer` to a `BaseMsgC`

PS. Maybe this is helpfull [DotNetty.Codecs.Protobuf](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty/tree/dev/src/DotNetty.Codecs.Protobuf)

Comment: It is very useful.  

But i cant decode ByteString type msg;
-  (BaseMsgC)message {{ "msgType": "001login", "msg": "dGhlIGlzIHRlc3QgbXNn" }} BaseMsgC

The msg is fault result;  


The Java Server send msg is 

"the is test msg"

Comment: I have no idee what a BaseMsgC is but could it be that you just need to decode the 'msg' field with base64